# E/F is Galois ext with $[E:F]=p^2$ and its Galois group is not cyclic, then $\exists K$ a proper subfield of $E$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, galois-theory, galois-extensions

Let $E$ be a Galois extension of a field $F$. Suppose that the Galois group $Gal(E/F)$ is an abelian group of order $p^2$ which is not cyclic.

Then I want to show

> $\exists K$  a proper subfield of $E$, such that $K=F(\alpha)$ for some $\alpha\in E$ when $K$ is a proper subfield of $E$,

and want to know

> how many numbers of subfields $K$ such that $ F\subsetneq K\subsetneq E$

---

From group theory what I know is $\operatorname{Gal}(E/F) \simeq \mathbb{Z}_p \times \mathbb{Z}_p$ and it has following subgroup : $1, \mathbb{Z}_p, \mathbb{Z}_p\times \mathbb{Z}_p$.  I am trying to see via Galois correspondence, but it makes me more complicated.

Comment: Be careful about the subgroup lattice.

Comment: Note that $\Bbb Z_p \times \Bbb Z_p$ has multiple subgroups of the type $\Bbb Z_p$. For example, $\Bbb Z_p$ appears isomorphically as $\Bbb Z_p \times \{1\}$, $\{1\} \times \Bbb Z_p$ and even $\{(a, a) : a \in \Bbb Z_p\}$. The Galois correspondence will then give you a subfield corresponding to *each* subgroup and not just the isomorphism type.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The existence of an intermediate field $K$ is guaranteed by the Galois correspondence.
The fact that $K$ is generated by exactly one element over $F$, i.e $K = F(\alpha)$, is guaranteed from the fact that $[K:F] = p$.

The Galois correspondence gives you a different intermediate field for each subgroup of $\mathbb{Z}_p \times \mathbb{Z}_p$. So, to find the number of these intermediate fields, you just need to find the number of subgroups (non-trivial subgroups obviously). Moreover, any subgroup of $\mathbb{Z}_p \times \mathbb{Z}_p$ has order $p$ so it suffices to count the subgroups of order $p$.

Any two subgroups of order $p$ intersect trivially. There are $p-1$ non-identity elements in any subgroup, so the number of subgroups is given by $x$ where $(p-1)x = p^2 -1$. We conclude $x = p+1$. Therefore, there are $p+1$ intermediate fields.

Comment: Can you explain more about this?

>Since (p−1)(p+1)=p2−1, we can conclude Zp×Zp has p+1 subgroups of order p. Therefore, we have p+1 such fields.

Comment: I edited it and hopefully it's more clear.